# Sparse data/columns (EAV, dynamic columns/blobs?)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am designing a database for an application where there are customers which have multiple appointments.

Appointments are partially the same in that they all have a date (timestamp), assigned employee (int, foreign key -> employee table), kind of appointment (int, foreign key -> appointmentTypes), etcetera.

So far so good, the information above can all be inserted in nice relational tables with columns for each property.

The thing is that there are multiple kind of appointments which all have different questions. If it is a first-time appointment for example different questions are asked when it is a return appointment. There are dozens of different types of appointments, and there will be more added later (which will have questions that do not yet exist).

What to do with these dynamic questions which are different per kind? I have some options that I have thought of myself:

- Adding all of the columns to the appointment-table. Disadvantage: a very wide table with columns that are not used for many of the rows. Many columns are only used for SOME of the rows.
- EAV. Disadvantage: the known disadvantages of EAV. Many joins, many rows in the EAV-table. People say it is hard to manage when it gets larger.
- A BLOB with all of the dynamic columns as JSON/XML. Disadvantage: more difficult to select data based on criteria. Difficult to impose requirements on the column data.
- Dynamic columns (possible in MariaDB). Disadvantage: it looks similar to the BLOB with JSON/XML, so I guess it has the same disadvantages, but I'm not sure.
- Making different tables for all kinds of appointments. Disadvantage: dozens of tables that have to be joined for each of the appointment. Some appointments have the same fields, which would have to be available in all of the tables that share these properties.

My question is the following: knowing that every solution will be imperfect, what is considerd best practice? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Best practice is what best models your requirements and exposes the least amount of disadvantages.

Comment: You can use JSON/XML blob and say "well since I don't need to filter based on the questions being asked... the disadvantage exists but does not affect me".

Comment: You can use the EAV approach and say "since I have a ready-made EAV library that helps me run the many joins needed to work with EAV... and since my application can withstand some slower data retrieval due to the EAV then the disadvantages of EAV exist but do not affect me.".

Comment: I'd either use the sparse/dynamic columns feature because it's "cleaner" in my application code or I'd use the multiple table approach because it's clearer and more straight forward (easier to maintain for future developers on the project etc.).

Comment: Yea.. I'm down with EAV. Use your RDBMS the way it was designed to be used and you'll have less to fight with as your app matures. In the end, how many types of appointments, and questions for each type do you have?

Comment: On the multiple table subject I'd also say that table relations can be nicely mapped. Common table content can be regarded as "hasOne" relations or "isA" / "extends" relation making the application code map to the table structure less complex than it would initially seem.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Mihai Stancu! @JNevill, at the start 50-100 types but the amount will increase. The questions will be different, some types will have dozens of questions while other types will only have a few questions (5-10).

Comment: So if you store your questions in a `questions` table with fields `question_id|appt_type|question` then, properly indexed, it shouldn't take but a fraction of second to pull questions for a particular `appt_type`. Even at 50 questions for each `appt_type` and 300 appt_types, you are still at only 15000 records. That's chump change.

Comment: @JNevill, the questions aren't the problem, but the answers to the questions need to be stored as well. There are (at the moment) 500.000 customers with dozens of appointments per customer. With EAV you should do something like Appt_id|Key|Value